# Forced slowdown in a web application

Tags: java, tomcat, selenium, jetty

To write quality Selenium tests with all the proper "waits", I'm currently forcing a web application to run slower with this:

```
public class SlowLoadingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new ServletException("SlowLoadingFilter sleep failed", e);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
```

I'd like to know if there is a proper way to do that with Tomcat or Jetty, or is this the only way?

Comment: How exactly is this connected to Selenium? Are you trying to change your server's behaviour to make your Selenium tests pass?

Comment: When writing selenium tests you have to wait for elements all the time and if the webapp is too fast, you may miss some waits and the test will break once in a while if anything slows down a bit. I added this information to the question, indeed it was not clear

Comment: What. Usually the problem is Selenium being too fast and the webapp/browser playing catch-up which causes stale elements, not yet visible elements or even not yet existing elements to be requested. If the webapp is fast, then you don't need any waits in your Selenium code, it will mostly just work.

Comment: but "mostly" is not enough, the tests must be always successful, even if something occasionally slows down the webapp, that's why I need something to force this to happen

Comment: Aha! Now I get it, now I get what you're trying to do. Nice thinking. You could think about tagging the question with [tomcat] and/or [jetty] to attract server people. Or maybe try http://serverfault.com?